# How to dynamically add new columns with the datatypes to the existing Delta table and update the new columns with values

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

Scenario:

df1 ---> Col1,Col2,Col3 -- which  are the columns in the  delta table

df2 ---> Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 -- which are the columns in the latest refresh table

1. How to get the new columns (in the above Col4,Col5) with datatypes dynamically.
2. How to alter the existing Delta table to include the  new    columns (in the above Col4,Col5) dynamically and update the new  column values

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean under "get new columns with datatypes dynamically"? What is the source of refresh table?

Comment: @Alex Ott - Thanks for response. Source of refresh table is the  csv file  from the blob storage, which is loaded and converted into the table with createOrReplaceTempView.  when I say dynamically means something that is equal to in sql - select column_name,data_type from information_schema.columns where table = createOrReplaceTempViewtablename. In Databricks we have printschema, Describe to see the metadata of the table but how to get the columns and datatypes like in SQL so that I can use forloop to ALTER TABLE deltatable ADD {column_name} {data_type}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to perform explicit `ALTER TABLE` if you have Delta table - you just need to use built-in capabilities for schema evolution ([blog post](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/09/24/diving-into-delta-lake-schema-enforcement-evolution.html)) - just add the `mergeSchema` option with value `true`, and Delta will take care for updating schema.  For example, if I have initial table with two fields: `i1` & `i2`:

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([[1,2]], schema="i1 int, i2 int")
df1.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("test")
```

then I can update it even if I have more columns:

```py
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([[1,2, '1']], schema="i1 int, i2 int, v string")
df2.write.format("delta").mode("append") \
  .option("mergeSchema", "true").saveAsTable("test")
```

You can find more information about schema evolution & enforcement in the following [blog post](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/09/24/diving-into-delta-lake-schema-enforcement-evolution.html) and [this webinar](https://databricks.com/discover/diving-into-delta-lake-talks/schema-enforcement-evolution).

Comment: Thanks for your help it worked. Is there any way that we can do this with merge  with condition  matched and unmatched for updates and inserts.

Comment: yes, it's possible - you need to set a special property for that - see docs: https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-update.html#automatic-schema-evolution